# Windows 2003 Server Name and Exchange server name

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange

My question is: Suppose I have three Exchange severs in one domain. My domain name is "anydomain.com".

1. Do all these servers need to be on different computers or can they reside on the same computer.
2. Does the name of Exchange server and Windows server on which it is installed need to be the same or are they always the same?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange is really just a set of services on a server.  They don't get a name themselves that is separate from the server name.  So:

1) Yes, each of the 3 Exchange servers need to be their own server (virtual or physical).

2) The name of the server is the only name that you can use to communicate with the Exchange Services on it.

Just remember that if you are talking about virtualized servers, they are still independent servers that have their own names, they are just sharing hardware with the host server.